# iPhone / DirectX : 3D models question

Tags: iphone, directx, models, 3d

Sorry for the random question

Years ago I built a 3D world in directX.  If I remember the models were in .x and I even had characters that were animated.

Last night it hit me that it would be fun to put this in to iOS as I been playing with openGL quite a bit

So Question!  **Can you convert animated .x files so they can be used in iOS**

Comment: Have you tried to convert .x file to .3ds or .md2?

Comment: No not yet, can they be used on the iPhone

Comment: Look at this link http://kode80.com/2009/09/24/iphone-md2-example/

Comment: Post this as a answer as it rocks, Delimitry you rule!

Comment: Oh and to convert formats, Milkshake 3D seems a good bet